# Loop the list if a list, or a new list with the object in it if an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to exactly as the title says, so I thought of a short way of doing this. But it won't work:

```
var json = "{\"prop\": \"value\"}";

(JSON.parse(json).forEach ? JSON.parse(json) : [JSON.parse(json)]).forEach(function(item) {
    alert('Looped');
});
```

Why won't this work? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uawy43ps/3/)

Comment: Oh, yeah, rushed when writing the example.

Comment: why did you decide that it doesn't work? It alerts 'Looped' as expected

Comment: Apparently it was just a bracket typo. Voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.isArray()` comes in handy here:

```js
var json = '{"prop": "value"}';

var parsedJson = JSON.parse(json);
var myArray = Array.isArray(parsedJson) ? parsedJson : [parsedJson];

myArray.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log('looped');
});
```

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

Comment: I am aware of this solution. I am just curious why won't mine work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Your solution works if you add the missing bracket after the ternary operator and fix the JSON: https://jsfiddle.net/3ds8xf9h/ -- it is still not necessary a good idea to check whether the the parsed JSON is an array by checking if it has a function `forEach`.